# Safety of magic setters in PHP

Tags: object-oriented, php

I don't know how in else languages, but in PHP seems to me that they are very unsafe way how to set value of any member variable - because **one setter cannot easily validate input for many variables** (mostly if they are of various types)

Most examples of magic setters say only

```
public $prop = array();

public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->prop[$name] = $value;
}
```

There is not any validation. And it is wrong.

Even if I would add validation, still I cannot easily validate all types, because code of function would be very very long.

## Problem

- Is any way how to make magic setters safe?
- or is it really better to avoid their using (define own setter for each member variable)?

Comment: For reasons of encapsulation, if each variable requires its own validation, it should have its own setter.

Comment: As David Pecker said, it is *much* better to write *action* related methods rather than *setting* methods. Setting that aside *(pun intended)*, I would only even consider magic setters in cases where I **could not write dedicated methods**; i.e. there are dynamic class properties. But I can't think of an example where that is the case... so, until I do, I will never use magic setters.

Comment: Could this be useful to hook invalidation of a cached hash value into the setters when there are no invalid parameters?

Comment: why is writing all the validation in __set any more difficult than writing it separately in many different functions?

Answer (score 1):

The use case for magic setters is different than when data has constraints. Typically magic setters are used for Data Transfer Objects. PDO is one such case where the results of a database query can be returned as objects rather than associative arrays. Internally, these PDO objects are using magic setters and getters. Other valid use cases are when there simply are no constraints on the data that can be assigned to the property.

As soon as you restrict values based on some set of rules, magic setters become a burden. Traditional private fields and mutator methods become the recommended approach so you can enforce encapsulation and data hiding.

The question about making magic setters safe is not well defined. Security is a concern, of course, but that gets limited to how the application uses the keys and values of the internal `$prop` array.

The one thing I would recommend is to make `$prop` a private field. Just because you are using magic setters doesn't mean the backing array needs to be public.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious dirty way to deal with this is to have a `switch` statement inside your `__set` method, throwing an exception if an invalid (ie. unsupported) value is trying to be set, through the `default` case, otherwise either directly assigning the `name => value` pair of running the pair throu a method to validate it.

If you are using some kind of modern IDE (I can only speak for PhpStorm, but I am sure other IDEs support it too), you can then annotate the class in question with the `@property` PhpDoc annotation and your IDE will suggest the properties of the class.

Still, if you are modeling a class for your domain, I would refrain from plain setters all together and use more descriptive names of methods, such as `change[Property]` to overwrite an encapsulated variable, `add[Item]` to add another item to a private/protected collection and so on.

Either way, for your domain classes, the [TellDon'tAsk](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle is quite often a very good pattern to follow, followed by throwing domain exceptions on failures.

Comment: Currently I am using NetBeans. Yes, it can call type of variable, read mostly from `@var` - or also from the first usage of any variable (simply translate `$var = array()` as array type, or `$var = 0` as integer type).

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean with *no validation*? PHP isn't strictly typed, it is up to mostly you, to validate inputs. If you write your owner setter/method/function, you will still need to validate. From the perspective of validation - I don't see a difference between magic methods, and any regular function. Btw, in PHP you can enforce array type and objects in method arguments.

**Edit**
You do use magic methods, when it is appropriate. No one is forcing you to use them instead of a regular method. There will be situations when you might want to use them.

As to your question, my point is still the same: whether it is a magic method, or a regular method of your class that accepts arguments, it is your responsibility to validate them. It has nothing to do with the safety of magic methods.

Comment: Those words about missing validation is strictly related to example above. And else, I am worried about that you are wrong about difference between regular method and magic one, in case of setters.

Comment: What are you talking about? I think we are talking about different things.  Regular PHP methods and magic methods alike - are all prone to variable mishaps. You need to validate your input whether its a magic method or not.

Comment: Look top - magic setter behaves in a different way- `_set` behave like `$object -> variable = $value` - but `__call` behaves like a standard function and covers all functions, unless there is limitation (inside of `__call`) that it cannot be used on group of functions (mostly private and protected).

Comment: We are discussing here validation of arguments, as was asked in the question and my response is valid. I know how magic functions behave, you dont need to explain me that.